# Magento2.3.4 - No such entity with customerId

Tags: magento2

I imported all my **Customers** from my `Old Magento store`.

But now, when a **Customer** try to log in in my new store with a wrong password, they can see this error:

[image]

Can someone tell me how I can fix it please?

Many thanks

Comment: try to disable Bss_LoginAsCustomer module

Comment: share the mentioned plugin class code